# Xcode iPhone - Base SDK, Active SDK difference?

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk, base-sdk

What's the difference between the *"Base SDK for all configurations"* and the *"Active SDK"* in Xcode?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The "Active SDK" value is effectively a build-time override of your "Base SDK" value, and determines which version of the SDK is used to build your application. In general, you should build your application against the latest *stable* SDK (at the moment, that's the non-beta 3.0 SDK), and set your "iPhone OS Deployment Target" to the version of the oldest device you intend to support (e.g. 2.2.1).